# Find a Backbone.js View if you know the Model?

Tags: backbone.js

Given a page that uses Backbone.js to have a Collection tied to a View (`RowsView`, creates a `<ul>`) which creates sub Views (`RowView`, creates `<li>`) for each Model in the collection, I've got an issue setting up inline editing for those models in the collection.

I created an `edit()` method on the `RowView` view that replaces the `li` contents with a text box, and if the user presses `tab` while in that text box, I'd like to trigger the `edit()` method of the next View in the list.

I can get the model of the next model in the collection:

```
// within a RowView 'keydown' event handler
var myIndex = this.model.collection.indexOf(this.model);
var nextModel = this.model.collection.at(myIndex+1);
```

But the question is, how to find the View that is attached to that Model. The parent `RowsView` View doesn't keep a reference to all the children Views; it's `render()` method is just:

```
this.$el.html(''); // Clear
this.model.each(function (model) {
    this.$el.append(new RowView({ model:model} ).render().el);
}, this);
```

Do I need to rewrite it to keep a separate array of pointers to all the `RowView`s it has under it? Or is there a clever way to find the View that's got a known Model attached to it?

Here's a jsFiddle of the whole problem: http://jsfiddle.net/midnightlightning/G4NeJ/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not elegant to store a reference to the View in your model, however you could link a View with a Model with events, do this:

```
// within a RowView 'keydown' event handler
var myIndex = this.model.collection.indexOf(this.model);
var nextModel = this.model.collection.at(myIndex+1);
nextModel.trigger('prepareEdit');
```

In RowView listen to the event prepareEdit and in that listener call edit(), something like this:

```
this.model.on('prepareEdit', this.edit);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that your `RowsView` should keep track of its component `RowView`s. The individual `RowView`s really are parts of the `RowsView` and it makes sense that a view should keep track of its parts.

So, your `RowsView` would have a `render` method sort of like this:

```
render: function() {
    this.child_views = this.collection.map(function(m) {
        var v = new RowView({ model: m });
        this.$el.append(v.render().el);
        return v;
    }, this);
    return this;
}
```

Then you just need a way to convert a <kbd>Tab</kbd> to an index in `this.child_views`.

---

One way is to use events, Backbone views have `Backbone.Events` mixed in so views can trigger events on themselves and other things can listen to those events. In your `RowView` you could have this:

```
events: {
    'keydown input': 'tab_next'
},
tab_next: function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode != 9)
        return true;
    this.trigger('tab-next', this);
    return false;
}
```

and your `RowsView` would `v.on('tab-next', this.edit_next);` in the `this.collection.map` and you could have an `edit_next` sort like this:

```
edit_next: function(v) {
    var i = this.collection.indexOf(v.model) + 1;
    if(i >= this.collection.length)
        i = 0;
    this.child_views[i].enter_edit_mode(); // This method enables the <input>
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/WeCRW/

A variant on this would be to add a reference to the `RowsView` to the `RowView`s and then `tab_next` could directly call `this.parent_view.edit_next()`.

---

Another option is to put the `keydown` handler inside `RowsView`. This adds a bit of coupling between the `RowView` and `RowsView` but that's probably not a big problem in this case but it is a bit uglier than the event solution:

```
var RowsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    events: {
        'keydown input': 'tab_next'
    },
    render: function() {
        this.child_views = this.collection.map(function(m, i) {
            var v = new RowView({ model: m });
            this.$el.append(v.render().el);
            v.$el.data('model-index', i); // You could look at the siblings instead...
            return v;
        }, this);
        return this;
    },
    tab_next: function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode != 9)
            return true;
        var i = $(e.target).closest('li').data('model-index') + 1;
        if(i >= this.collection.length)
            i = 0;
        this.child_views[i].enter_edit_mode();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZnxZv/